# NoReverseMatch at /; error at line 0

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm getting the below error and I have no idea why... I swear everything was working fine yesterday... I'm using python 3.5 and django 1.9. I went through most of the NOReverseMatch posts, but I couldn't find anything... please help

```
"Reverse for 'xxx' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []"
```

and

```
In template F:\Django-tutorial\src\landing_pages\templates\landing_pages\home.html, error at line 0
```

home.html should be displayed as a main page

My projects url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^', include('landing_pages.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^in/', include('web_monitor.urls')),
```

]

landing_pages.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from landing_pages.views import home, contact, about, cost


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^about/$', about, name='about'),
    url(r'^cost/$', cost, name='cost'),
]
```

Home.html:

```
{% extends 'landing_pages/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block jumbotron %}
<!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% include 'landing_pages/head_css.html' %}
</head>

<body>
{% include 'landing_pages/nav_bar.html' %}
<div class="container">
    {% block jumbotron %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

nav_bar.html is just a nav bar, where i reference links like this:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'cost' %}">Cost</a></li>
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `home.html` template.

Comment: updated with all the html files...

Comment: Assuming the `xxx` in your error is not something you have redacted, there must be something in your templates somewhere that is doing something like `{% url 'xxx' %}`. Can you post the full stack trace that is generated?

Comment: i had a comment in nav_bar like this: `<li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li> <!-- {% url 'xxx'%} refers to urls.py "name" -->` and that's what was causing it... :O I guess django doesnt accept comments in html files for parts of django code?

Comment: Yes, it would. Django does not recognise HTML comments (`<!-- -->`) and will still parse any template tags inside there.

Comment: You can use django template comments instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/templates/#comments